# Edit proguard-project.txt in cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am using cordova to build my application. In this app, i am building a cordova plugin. In android section of plugin, i need to include another service. But to include that service i need to add some lines in **build.gradle** and **proguard-project.txt** files.

I can edit Gradle file by adding my own gradle file as below

```
<framework src="relative/path/your.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

But i can't find how to add some code in proguard-project.txt.

**Anyone have any idea how to add some lines to proguard-project.txt?**

Comment: you can use cordova-plugin-proguard for it https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 0):

The proguard-rules.pro file is where you can add custom ProGuard rules.

By default, this file is located at the root of the module (next to the build.gradle file).

To add more ProGuard rules that are specific to each build variant, add another proguardFiles property in the corresponding productFlavor block.

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
               'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
        proguardFile 'flavor2-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

read more [Shrink Your Code and Resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

I searched high and low on the internet and couldn't find the answer, but I got lucky and figured it out!  In my case, I have an Ionic / Angular application (I'm still on Ionic v3, but this will probably work with v4 as well).

1. Create a file in the `src/assets/` folder called `proguard-custom.txt` and add your custom attributes here.

   - In my case `cordova-plugin-proguard` was having issues with `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` so I added these lines to resolve that

     ```
     -keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** { *; } 
     -keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
     ```
2. If you already have cordova-plugin-proguard installed on your project, remove it and re-add it. Adding the plugin grabs your configs from your custom .txt file.

   ```
   ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-proguard
   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-proguard
   ```
3. Add / remove the Android platform

   ```
   ionic cordova platform rm android
   ionic cordova platform add android
   ```
4. You can verify that your custom settings have been added by looking at the `/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/proguard-custom.txt` file.  You will see all the default options that the cordova-plugin-proguard plugin adds, but at the bottom of the file you should see everything that you added to your proguard-custom.txt file!

So now you don't have to worry about changing this file manually everytime you build the Android app.  Just remember that anytime you change the `src/assets/proguard-custom.txt` file, you have to remove and add the cordova-plugin-proguard plugin.